# AngularJS typeahead tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, typeahead, angular-ui-typeahead

I'm using [AngularJS typeahead](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), I made an autocomplete input with it, using custom templates (to add the photo and the name of the person that I'm typing) and it's working fine.

```
<input ng-model="data.friend"
       typeahead="recipient as recipient.Name for recipient in loadStudents($viewValue)"
       typeahead-template-url="/Content/js/inbox/partials/typeaheadTemplate.html"
       typeahead-wait-ms="300"
       typeahead-editable="false"
       typeahead-min-length="1"
       type="text" class="col_100 input radius2x transition boxsizing"
       auto-focus />
```

But now I need it to be for more than one person, which means a tag-like system. 
How can I do that with Angular typeahead?

Comment: I just completed something exactly like this. What I did was create a Directive that puts the typeahead and below it a scrollable DIV. Next to the typeahead I put an ADD button. When you choose the name you click Add (or hit return) and it puts the item down in the DIV below. Now you can put as many as you wish. YOu can put a 'Remove' link next to items in the DIV if you wish. If you want to get MORE creative I also made a typeahead that allows you to put in a comma separated list of names. That required basically creating a typeahead from scratch, however.

Comment: can you put this code as an answer? thanks!